# determine consumer and producer surpleus

Tags: integration

Demand equation:
$$p=60-\frac{50q}{\sqrt{q^2+3600}}$$

Supply equation:
$$p=10\ln(q+20)-26$$

Determine consumers’ surplus and producers’ surplus under market equilibrium. Round your answer to the nearest integer

Answer should be consumer surplus $1197$ and producers surplus $477$.

I can't figure out how to go around this problem, I tried trying to solve for $q$ and $p$ and then integrate but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

(Fortunately, I'd seen these definitions in the text I've been teaching out of for the past two semesters...)

You need to find the values of $ \ q \ $ and  $ \ p \ $  at which the demand and supply curves intersect.  A graph is helpful since simply setting the functions equal gives you an equation that can't be solved algebraically.  It turns out the curves meet *close* to  $ \ Q \ = \ 80 \ , \ P \ = \ 20 \  $ .  (As a check, the demand function gives $ \ p \ = \ 60 \ - \ \frac{4000}{\sqrt{10000}} \ = \ 60 \ - \ 40 \ $ and the supply function, $ \ p \ = \ 10 \ln 100 \ - \ 26 \ \approx \ 46 \ - \ 26 \ $ . )

The consumer's surplus is then nearly

$$ \ \int_0^{Q} \ \ (60-\frac{50q}{\sqrt{q^2+3600}}) - P \ \ dq \ \ = \ \int_0^{80} \ \ (60-\frac{50q}{\sqrt{q^2+3600}}) - 20 \ \ dq \ \ $$

and the producer's surplus is nearly

$$ \ \int_0^{Q} \ \ P \ - \ (10 \ln [q+20] \ - \ 26)  \ \ dq \ \ = \ \int_0^{80} \ \ 20 \ - \ (10 \ln [q+20] \ - \ 26)  \ \ dq \ \ .  $$

You'll find that these definite integrals have values close to the indicated answers.  (I got 1200 and 474 . )  More precise values for the coordinates of the intersection point  $ \ (Q, \ P) \ $ should give you a better match.

Comment: I have been attempting this problem for days. I kept trying to equate the equations but I could not do so because as you said they can't be solved algebraically. thank you so much!